# Message box for multiple condition

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, authentication, passwords

I have this code:

```
Class Form1
    Function ValidatePassword(ByVal pwd As String, Optional ByVal minLength As Integer = 8, Optional ByVal numUpper As Integer = 1, Optional ByVal numLower As Integer = 1, Optional ByVal numNumbers As Integer = 1) As Boolean
        Dim upper As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[A-Z]")
        Dim lower As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[a-z]")
        Dim number As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[0-9]")

        If Len(pwd) < minLength Then
            MsgBox("Password must consist of 8 characters as minimum!")
            Return False
        End If

        If upper.Matches(pwd).Count < numUpper Then
            MsgBox("Password must consist of uppercase letter!")
            Return False
        End If

        If lower.Matches(pwd).Count < numLower Then
            MsgBox("Password must consist of lowercase letter!")
            Return False
        End If

        If number.Matches(pwd).Count < numNumbers Then
            MsgBox("Password must consist of at least 1 digit character!")
            Return False
        End If

        MsgBox("Password OK!")
        Return True
    End Function
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label3.Text = ValidatePassword(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

it works well to give me message if one of the condition is fulfilled. I want to get something like:
For example, the input: **askjf**

then message box showed:

1. Password must consist of 8 characters as minimum!
2. Password must consist of uppercase letter!
3. Password must consist of at least 1 digit character!

Can anybody help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `List(Of String)` to store each error as it is encountered.

After all the checks are done, if your `List` has more than zero items then you should show the errors in a message box. Otherwise, the test was passed.

Here's some sample code:

```
Function ValidatePassword(ByVal pwd As String, Optional ByVal minLength As Integer = 8, Optional ByVal numUpper As Integer = 1, Optional ByVal numLower As Integer = 1, Optional ByVal numNumbers As Integer = 1) As Boolean
    Dim upper As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[A-Z]")
    Dim lower As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[a-z]")
    Dim number As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[0-9]")

    'create a new list to store any errors
    Dim messageList As New List(Of String)
    'create a boolean to handle true/ false result
    Dim checkResult As Boolean

    'add messages as necessary depending on the checks
    If Len(pwd) < minLength Then
        messageList.Add("Password must consist of 8 characters as minimum!")
    End If

    If upper.Matches(pwd).Count < numUpper Then
        messageList.Add("Password must consist of uppercase letter!")
    End If

    If lower.Matches(pwd).Count < numLower Then
        messageList.Add("Password must consist of lowercase letter!")
    End If

    If number.Matches(pwd).Count < numNumbers Then
        messageList.Add("Password must consist of at least 1 digit character!")
    End If

    ' check for any error messages
    If messageList.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Password OK!")
        checkResult = True
    Else
        'join the list items together using new line as separator for formatting
        MessageBox.Show(Join(messageList.ToArray, vbCrLf))
        checkResult = False
    End If

    'result of function
    Return checkResult

End Function
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but I got these errors: 'Count' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Message' and name 'result' is not declared.

Comment: I ran this code on a vb.net winforms project and it ran without errors. I've updated the code to use a different variable name to avoid any name conflicts. Maybe try it again.

Comment: great! Thank you very much